# Liferay Export LAR Automation Programatically or thru liferay Console

Tags: java, automation, export, liferay-6, schedule

I am looking for a way to automate the export .lar file feature in Liferay EE. I would like to schedule the .lar export weekly/monthly/after every update/change pro-grammatically or using Liferay Console.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in Liferay?